# Count the recurrence of a word

Tags: javascript, string, object

I am writing a function called "countWords".

Given a string, "countWords" returns an object where each key is a word in the given string, with its value being how many times that word appeared in th given  string.

Notes:
* If given an empty string, it should return an empty object.

```
function countWords(str) {
  var obj = {};

  var split = str.split(" ");

  return split;
}

var output = countWords('ask a bunch get a bunch'); 
console.log(output); // --> MUST RETURN {ask: 1, a: 2, bunch: 2, get: 1}
```

Have any idea?

Comment: Smells like homework? :)

Comment: Please, do some research before asking on Stack Overflow. See [ask]. There are literally hundreds of questions on her about counting the number of occurrences of words in string. Pick one that's showing in the Related section to the right and follow it.

Comment: Besides `return split`, what have you tried?

Answer (score 1):

I wont give you finished code ( thats not the sense of a homework) , but i try to get you to solve the problem on your own.

So far you've already got an array of words.

Next lets declare an object we can assign the properties later.

Then we'll iterate over our array and if the array element doesnt exist in our object as key yet ( *if(!obj[array[i]])*) well create a new property, with elements name and the value 1.( *obj[array[i]=1;* )

If the element is a key of that object, lets increase its value. 
( *obj[array[i]]++;*)

Then return the object.

Answer (score 0):

So you could use a javascript Map for this like so:

```
var myMap = new Map();
myMap.set(keyString, count);
```

and access the value of the key like so:

```
myMap.get(keyString);
```

For more information you can read up here https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map

Comment: This does not solve the problem ( required to return an object ), and the problem is unsolvable.

Comment: Hi @Jonasw, myMap is a map object so i guess returning myMap is returning an object, no?
What can be done is checking whether myMap.get("word") exists - if it does then get its value, increment it by one and then set it again.
If the key does not exist then set it... As simple as that

Comment: But suggesting Map to a beginner isnt the best idea. Also in this case it is not neccessary to use a map. And map is an object but not an object.

Comment: @Jonasw I do somewhat disagree, instead of completing OP's homework and teaching OP nothing, BroBan gave a really helpful answer. Also, why teach beginners to (ab)use objects when there is a ready-made `Map` with simple, descriptive interface?

Comment: @le_m from the question: *MUST RETURN {ask: 1, a: 2, bunch: 2, get: 1}*

Comment: @Jonasw Yes, I agree with you on that, this answer doesn't fulfill OPs homework spec. But it points out an alternative, IMHO superior (especially for beginners) solution. I just consider this more helpful than simply providing OP with a solution for his homework.

Comment: @le_m yes shure. I appreciate any kind of additional information ( im not the downvoter). But if theres an requirenment in the question, the answerer should notice the OP that this requirement isnt fullfilled...